# Argument not serializable PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a strange error, I'm running a PowerShell script in DevOps and at the end I want the contents sent to a storage account, I use the snippet below, which works in PowerShell ISE

```
$strgrg = "storage-rg"
$StorageAccountName = "storageaccount2021"
$ContainerName = "container1"
$Filename = "nsg.txt"

$endtime = (get-date).AddHours("2")
$ctx = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $strgrg -Name $StorageAccountName).context
$StorageAccountKey = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Context $ctx -Name $ContainerName -Permission racwdl -ExpiryTime $endtime
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -file ./$Filename  -Container $ContainerName -Blob $Filename -Context $ctx -force
```

The error I get is:

```
 WARNING: System.ArgumentException: Argument passed in is not serializable.
 Parameter name: value at System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.set_Item(Object key, Object value)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper.PopulatePropertiesFromQos(AzurePSQoSEvent qos, IDictionary`2 eventProperties, Boolean populateException)
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.MetricHelper.LogUsageEvent(AzurePSQoSEvent qos)
```

I put some debugging in and it looks like the error occurs after `$endtime = (get-date).AddHours("2")` when it's running the following line, but that seems fine `$ctx = (Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $strgrg -Name $StorageAccountName).context`

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does the error indicate which of the 3 Az calls triggered the error?

Comment: Note that a `Warning` is technically not an error, so you might be able to simply ignore it.